# "トゥーリが森に行く時のメンバー"

Tags: meaning, subjects

> 三人はトゥーリが森に行く時のメンバーで、どうやらマインも森に連れて行ってもらったことがあるようだ。([source: 本好きの下剋上](https://books.google.com/books?id=0M0NEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT220&lpg=PT220&dq=%22%E4%B8%89%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%81%8C%E6%A3%AE%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7%22&source=bl&ots=DDGJFuAhfZ&sig=ACfU3U03ScmiA5s8f1rSrgejfppRiKNqhw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSs-fp7YruAhUWCTQIHTYKBvgQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22%E4%B8%89%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%81%8C%E6%A3%AE%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7%22&f=false))

I am curious how to think about the subject here トゥーリが. Because the verb "with" is not used here. Any one have any advice on how to interpret the subject meaning in this case?

I kind of get the meaning that Toule (not sure the spelling is correct) is one of the three members who went out to forest and who also somehow brought Main with her.

Comment: [Context, please.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important) Where did you see this line? (I've actually Googled it and found out, but please always include the source where you can.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 三人は[[トゥーリが森に行く時]のメンバーで]、どうやらマインも森に連れて行ってもらったことがあるようだ。

Roughly speaking the sentence is to be parsed like this. Since it is only the first part of the sentence you are asking about, let's focus on that part at issue.

> トゥーリが森に行く時

"when トゥーリ went to the forest". トゥーリ is the subject of this action "to go".

> トゥーリが森に行く時のメンバー

"people who were with トゥーリ when トゥーリ went to the forrest" or "teammates who went to the forest with トゥーリ".

> 三人はトゥーリが森に行く時のメンバーで

Those three were with トゥーリ when トゥーリ went to the forest.

Comment: Thank you so much that explains it! I am very sorry I didn't provide context, will do next time! (It is that book which you found)

Comment: @user342453 Don't worry about it. Not a big deal. Providing details and context really helps answerers help you and shortens your average wait time for a quality answer.